# React App's Imported Object Doesn't Update Automatically On Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, import

Trying to change a piece of text based on whether a user clicked a button or not.

I've created a JS object to hold the text, I want to show and imported into the React app to display. However, each time I try to click the button, it only updates the page after I've clicked to another tab.

Code Sample:

export file

```
text_to_show = { title: "This is a title", name: "name"}
// button updates text_to_show to different title and name.
export { text_to_show }
```

import file

```
import { text_to_show } from './anotherfile'
<p>{text_to_show.title}</p>
```

Any thoughts or solutions to this issue?

Comment: You need to put in state. Otherwise React will not be aware that it needs to re-render.

Comment: You have to tie into the lifecycle with useState, useReducer, etc. State changes with useState forces a render, so it's immediately reflected in the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you save `title` property as a state in parent component, than use it as parameter for child component. Every time you change the state - it will immediately change.

Here is an example to do it:

```js
// import { useState } from 'react'
const {useState} = React

const ChildComponent = ({title, updateTitle}) => {
  return <div><h1>{title}</h1>
  <button onClick={()=>{ updateTitle('Child updated the title') }}>Change from child!</button>
  </div>
}

const ParrentComponent = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('Initial title')
  return <div>
    <button onClick={()=>{ setTitle('Updated from parent') }}>Change from parent!</button>
    <ChildComponent title={title} updateTitle={setTitle}/>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <ParrentComponent/>,
   document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```